# How to specify Unique Key in EF 7 Code First with Data Annotations

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations, code-first, entity-framework-core

You can specified a Unique Key with Fluent Api:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasIndex(u => u.Nickname)
            .IsUnique();
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
}
```

But can you do it with Data Annotations?

## Edit

Methods change in EF7 Beta 8:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .Index(u => u.Nickname)
        .Unique();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid create an `Index` using Data Annotation is not still supported in EF 7. Check this [link](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/indexes.html#data-annotations).

I also tried to find some info related with that subject in the last releases and I couldn't find anything.

[EF 7 beta 8 release notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2015/10/15/ef7-beta-8-available.aspx)

[EF 7 RC1 release notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/11/18/entity-framework-7-rc1-available.aspx)

I found now a [post](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/107) from one of the EF developers (divega) saying this:

> In EF7 we support defining indexes using the fluent API but not an
>   attribute, at least no yet. The IndexAttribute you are possibly
>   referring to is something we added to the EF 6.x package at some point
>   but never really became a standard DataAnnotation.
>
> We don't want to copy the original attribute from EF6 as is because
>   there are a few things in it that we would like to change. Also,
>   having it in DataAnnotations directly would likely make more sense
>   than adding it to the EF7 package.
>   I should mention though that it is highly unlikely that we will add
>   IndexAttribute in the EF7 RTM timeframe.

### Update 1

Apparently this is a feature that will not be added to EF Core, at least for now.

From [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/indexes):

> Indexes can not be configured using Data Annotations.

But you can do it using Fluent Api:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasIndex(b => b.Url)
        .HasName("Index_Url");
}
```

Comment: @TWilly, I have updated my question, I'm afraid there is not change yet, so if you need to define an index, you will need to use Fluent Api

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of built in support, you can use a custom attribute of your own to annotate model properties and apply in `OnModelCreating()`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        foreach (var prop in entity.GetProperties())
        {
            var index = prop.PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<IndexAttribute>();
            if (index != null)
            {
                entity.AddIndex(prop);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With a simple marker attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class IndexAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Then in your model class, just add the attribute to create a secondary index:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
}
```